# Отправка данных больших размеров с помощью Netty

Tags: java, netty

Пишу сервер на асинхронных сокетах и в связи с этим возникло 2 вопроса. Могу ли я увеличить размер буффера для отсылаемых данных чтобы Netty отсылал данных не пакетами в 1024 байт а пакетами 3096 байт. Второй вопрос заключается в том какой оптимальный размер буффера должен быть? Какие могут быть последствия от того что я например поставлю размер буффера в 30 мегабайт, сможет ли Netty за раз отправить такой большой объем информации и какие последствия могут быть для производительности сервера в случае слишком большого объема буффера для отправки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Размер буффера при отправке данных может быть задан свойством канала `SO_SNDBUF`:

```
bootstrap.setOption(SO_SNDBUF, 1024);
```

> Могу ли я увеличить размер буффера для отсылаемых данных чтобы Netty отсылал данных не пакетами в 1024 байт а пакетами 3096 байт.

Да, можешь, но при этом пакеты будут фрагментироваться из-за того, что они будут больше [MTU](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit).

> Какие могут быть последствия от того что я например поставлю размер буффера в 30 мегабайт

Увидишь ошибки в консоли/логе при отправке данных, скорее всего, т.к. в ядре Linux по умолчанию размер буфферов (`net.core.rmem_max`) явно меньше.

> Какие последствия могут быть для производительности сервера в случае слишком большого объема буффера для отправки?

Из-за фрагментации пакетов может снижаться скорость передачи, хотя снижение, скорее всего, будет незначительным. Буффер большого размера потенциально может привести к увеличенному использованию оперативной памяти.